# Check dimensions of numpy array in a for loop and then turn 2-D data into 1-D data

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am working with the polyfit-function to add a trendline to my dataset. Since I got a lot of datasets (a lot more than the four examples found herein), I would like to make a for loop in order to check the dimensions of the data -- as we know, the polyfit-function only accepts 1-D data. My novice approach utilizing `np.ravel()` is something like this:

```
import numpy as np

data_a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
data_b = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
data_c = np.transpose(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]))
data_d = np.array([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]])


for items in (data_a, data_b, data_c, data_d):
    if items.ndim == 1:
        print('It is an 1-D array -- no action needed.')
        print(items.ndim)
    elif items.ndim == 2:
        print('It is an 2-D array, please do not be alarmed, I will convert it for you.')
        items.ravel()
        print(items.ndim)
    else:
        print('It contains more than two dimensions.')

print(data_a.ndim)
print(data_b.ndim)
print(data_c.ndim)
print(data_d.ndim)
```

If I had used `np.ravel()` on any dataset outside the for loop, it works like intended. For example:

```
data_c_2 = data_c.ravel()
data_d_2 = data_d.ravel()
```

But since I have quite a few datasets, I would be better (in my, perhaps, idiotic mind) to iterate through it while checking the dimensions.

I would highly appreciate if anyone could find time to help me. I would also appreciate if someone could explain what I am doing wrong in my for loop, so that I will have a better understanding of it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one. `items.ravel()` returns a new array. Outside the loop you can use something like:

```
data = data.ravel()
```

You cannot do it inside the loop as you will only be changing the loop variable. If you want to ravel "in-place" you can use `np.resize`, from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize):

> Change shape and size of array in-place.

Therefore, simply replace:

```
items.ravel()
```

with:

```
items.resize(items.size)
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- I highly appreciate it.